# Can twin stars be born?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, space, stars

Stars are born through the fusion of light atoms and the star's nucleus. So let's say that as a star is being born, the nucleus split and creates two stars. Could this even happen? If so, would the stars be considered twins?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that definition of a star's creation from... light doesn't have atoms, and a star doesn't have a "nucleus". Stars are just clouds of hydrogen that got large enough for gravity to compress the centre to densities and temperatures where fusion could happen.

Comment: I just googled "can twin stars happen" and this question came first, **above the wikipedia article on binary stars**. THIS question!! That's quite an achievement. And you did it.  Anyone got a number for Red Dwarf's "Inquisitor"? I have a job for him....  ;-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Although astronomers have considered this phenomenon in the past, the data indicates that this isn't how stars are born. That said, yes, your premise works.

Here's how you make a star, in a nutshell:

1. Take [a big cloud of gas and dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloud).
2. Have the cloud grow until it reaches roughly [the Jeans length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeans_instability), at which point the cloud is unstable.
3. Let some perturbation - perhaps a shock wave from a supernova or radiation from other stars - create a change in density and pressure.
4. The cloud should collapse into a [protostar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protostar), a giant blob of gas that isn't quite the finished product.
5. Let the protostar contract via the [Kelvin-Helmholtz mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Helmholtz_mechanism) until it gets hot enough to fuse hydrogen.

Voila! A star is born.

Binary star systems do exist. The [leading theory for how they form](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~eco/AST541/Mary_Anne_Peters.pdf) is that fragmentation happens during the collapse of the cloud, meaning that it splits in two before a star begins to form. Each smaller collapsing cloud then forms a star, creating a binary system. Therefore, you can indeed have your "twin stars". The idea you're talking about resembles the so-called *fission hypothesis* ([see section 2 here](http://www.phys.lsu.edu/astro/nap98/bf.final.html)), where one protostar, early on, splits in two. There are quite a few problems with the idea, including features of the gas's compressibility. The fragmentation hypothesis is much more commonly accepted.

If you're looking for a more detailed overview of the topic, you may find [this paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1988ComAp..12..169B&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf) illuminating (pun intended).

Comment: So now I'm wondering, could it be possible for the stars to eventually collapse in on each other?

Comment: @JasonUlrich It could, actually, in some [contact binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_binary). [KIC 9832227](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIC_9832227) is a good example.

Comment: I wonder how did that fit in a nutshell.

Comment: @Yawz Well, you should take a look at the [*not nutshell version*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branches_of_physics#Summary), for comparison :P

Answer (score 4):

No, not *after* the star is born. But this is happening all the time during the star formation - this is called a binary star. However, there is no guarantee that binary system will consist of two twins - typically one star is bigger, and the other is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if a white main sequence star was hit by a red dwarf, you might be able to get two orange stars out of the deal, but that's just off the top of my head.  I don't have any specific experience looking at these collision in simulations (or papers on the same) to back up that idea (conservation of angular momentum might play a key roles).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_collision